# How to check whether a string is among the `options` of a `select` in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The html codes are like this:

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I was wondering how to write a function to test whether a `string` is among the `option` of a select, such as

```
test_in("volvo", "select1")      // Return True
test_in("asdf", "select1")      // Return False
test_in("AUDI", "select1")      // Return False
```

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
function test_in(value, selector) {
    return $(selector + " option[value=" + value + "]").length > 0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ5Ng/9/)

You might want to convert the casing if you want it to be less strict. Also I'm not sure how you want to handle cases where the `option` element has a different value attribute and text content. Which one is the deciding one for the test? The version I wrote checks the value attribute.

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments, the function I wrote takes an entire selector, so you have to include `#` for ids and `.` for classes (e.g. `#select1` in your case). I think this is the best approach as you aren't forced to use just ids for any select you want to check.

Comment: +1 - this will work with the examples in the question, however you will need to pass the selector with its type ( eg. `test_in('volvo', '#select1');` )

Comment: You're not escaping special characters in the selector query, so this can't be used generically.

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Care to explain further? To my eyes as long as you pass in a correct jQuery selector this will always work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Once you wrap the search into a generic function you have to make sure that the selector is *always* valid, e.g. some options may have an opening square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an actual jQuery function for it, here is something you could use. It accepts a regular expression as well as a string to search for in each option's value; only the first element of the jQuery collection is used to search through.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hasOption = function(re) {
        var options = this[0] && this[0].options || [],
        matches = re.test || function(val) {
            return val.indexOf(re) != -1;
        }

        for (var i = 0, item; item = options[i]; ++i) {
            if (matches.call(re, item.value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

To call it:

```
$('#select1').hasOption('volvo')); // true
$('#select1').hasOption('asdf')); // false
$('#select1').hasOption('AUDI')); // false
$('#select1').hasOption(/AUDI/i)); // true!
```

Comment: +1, thanks for displaying that adding functions to jQuery can be so easy and useful.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try using `indexOf` on the `options` array of the select control</strike>

Nope, `options` it's a nodeList, so try:

Try

```
var opts = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('#select1').options);
if (opts.filter(function(opt){return /mercedes/i.test(opt.value);}).length){
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `options` has an `indexOf()` because Chrome doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: Better, though it duplicates the array of options each time :)

Comment: This would be a better approach: `[].filter.call(opts, function(item) {
    return item.value == '13';
}).length`

Answer (score 1):

`$("#select1 option[value='volvo']").length` - if that equals to zero, you don't have it in the select.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't should be :)

Comment: If you check my answer I'm using this inside an actual `test_it` function.

Comment: Not a generic solution, because it requires escaping special characters in the selector query.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rfQga/2/

```
var test_in = function(val, target) {
    var select = document.getElementById(target),
    retVal = false,
    rgCheck = new RegExp(val, "g");

    var i = 0,
    opts = select.options,
    l = opts.length;

    for (;i<l;i++) {
        if (rgCheck.test(opts[i].value)) {
            retVal = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I love how these types of answers help us (me at least) keep perspective with the underlying language so as not to be wholly dependent on jQuery. Definitely up!

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
function test_in(value, selectId){
    var foundValue = null;
    $("#" + selectId + " > option").each(function() {
        if (this.text == value){
            foundValue = value;
            return false; // break the each iteration
        }
    });
    return (foundValue != null);
}
```

Comment: The idea is nice, but it will always return false.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$("#select1 > option").each(function() {
if($(this).val()=='volvo'){
alert("value is in the combobox");
}
});​
```

working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AeEJs/2/)